# Delphi - open form on left monitor

Tags: delphi, multiple-monitors

I want my application to always start on the left monitor (in case that there are more than 1 connected).

How can this be done? How to detect the left monitor number?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: You should searched on the web before asking - http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Handling_the_Screen

Comment: Any particular reason you don't want to allow a user to make their own choice as to which monitor and position is preferred?

Comment: I hope your uninstall program is well tested

Comment: @CraigYoung Something like this can make a lot of sense for inhouse applications. I'd probably just store the form position in the registry anyway.

Comment: @dummzeuch Even "in-house", different user's have different preferences. And even if for your own app for your own personal use, I'd say form position as per your comment is better. (Though monitor code can be handy to ensure saved position is still a valid monitor.)

Comment: @CraigYoung giving users the choice can be a problem sometimes and become a support nightmare. You can definitely trust me on that, I have been there and done that. Didn't like it a bit.

Comment: @dummzeuch I don't see how? The point is you just restore the same position/maximised sate when the form was closed. And as I said it's useful to use `Screen.Monitor` to check if form would still be visible if restored to saved position. (And yes I am familiar with the "support nightmare" if user changes monitor arrangement - which is the point of the previous sentence.) _Throwing out an extremely useful feature instead resolving a specific related use-case seems a little harsh to me._

Comment: First of all, it's not a commercial app. I'm only writing it for me.

Comment: The application has to be on the most left monitor because it's a sidebar and it makes no sense to appear on the middle screen for example. I'm working with mouse coordinates to make the form visible when i move the cursor to the most left position. Sure, it would also be possible to place the sidebar to the most right monitor on the right side, but as I said, the app is only for me and I like it on the left side ;-)

Comment: @Chris If your form "remembers its position", then you only need to set it once - and you get the exact same effect. As a bonus, any time you want to change it (for whatever reason) it's easy to do - _without having to recompile your program ;)_.

Comment: @Craig You are right, it would be a better solution for a desktop computer to remember the position, but it's a notebook and i am using it with different monitor setups on different docking stations. In this case I think remembering the position would not do the trick

Comment: Additionally, i do not turn the laptop off or close the sidebar when i go to another room (docking station) and I have to go there (and back) ~10 times a day. Now the app detects the displaychange automatically and it's always at the position I want it to be

Comment: @Chris You make a good point. Though saving separate positions/bounds 'per desktop configuration' means you can be flexible while meeting your requirement. E.g. layout 1) laptop only: left on screen. layout 2) monitor each side of laptop: left of left-most monitor layout 3) monitor above laptop: left of whichever monitor you choose. As to the other comment about "turn off laptop or close sidebar"... it's not necessary if your side-bar handles `WM_DISPLAYCHANGE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use this code fragment:

```
if Screen.MonitorCount > 1 then
begin
  MonList := TList<TMonitor>.Create;

  for I := 0 to Screen.MonitorCount - 1 do
    MonList.Add(Screen.Monitors[I]);

  // sort by screen.monitor.left coordinate
  MonList.Sort(TComparer<TMonitor>.Construct(
    function(const L, R: TMonitor): Integer
    begin
      Result := L.Left - R.Left;
    end));

  _MonitorNum := TMonitor(MonList[0]).MonitorNum;

  // free the list
  MonList.Destroy;
end;
```

Then _MonitorNum holds the number of the left most monitor.

Comment: No need to create instances of list classes, anon methods, sort etc. Just run over the monitors and identify the most left most one. `var MinValue, MinIndex: Integer; ... MinValue :=  Screen.Monitors[0].Left; MinIndex := 0; for i := 1 to Screen.MonitorCount - 1 do if Screen.Monitors[i].Left < MinValue then begin MinValue := Screen.Monitors[i].Left; MinIndex := i; end;` When the loop terminates, `MinIndex` identifies the leftmost monitor.

Comment: @David That is true.

Answer (score 0):

**FMX Applications will behave differently for Screens & Displays**

The code below is a little fiddle I used on Form Show to align the form to the top left of the screen of where the mouse is currently found.

```
var
  currentDisplay: TDisplay;
  mousePosition: TPointF;

begin
  if (Screen.DisplayCount > 0) then
  begin
    mousePosition := Screen.MousePos;
    currentDisplay := Screen.DisplayFromPoint(mousePosition);
    Left := (currentDisplay.PhysicalBounds.Left);
    Top := 0;
  end;
end;
```